# How to print the exec error code using ANT

Tags: http, jenkins, curl, ant, exec

I have my ANT file which uses exec task to create Jenkins job using cURL. Whether `exec` task is success or failed, the jenkins build will be succeeded. So I tried to use `resultproperty` in exec and tried to print the result, but it returns only 0.

```
<exec executable="curl" resultproperty="MyExecResult" failonerror="false">
            <arg value="-k" />
            <arg value="-X" />
            <arg value="GET" />
            <arg value="<MyJenkinsURL>config.xml" />
            <arg value="-o" />
            <arg value="<MyPath>\GET\config.xml" />
            <arg value="-u" />
            <arg value=":" />
            <arg value="--ntlm" />
        </exec>
<echo>MyExecResult-GET ::: ${MyExecResult}</echo>
```

How can I print the resultproperty value in this scenario to get the error code. Kindly provide inputs. Thanks!

Comment: If `resultproperty` is returning 0, that means your `exec` isn't failing. I'm not sure what you're trying to do here. Do you want your build to fail when `exec` fails? If so, set `failonerror="false"`.

Comment: I want to fail the build when exec fails, it doesn't work for me eventhough after setting failonerror="true". That is why I am trying to take the error code, and unable to get that.

Comment: It sounds like your curl command simply isn't failing. Can you post the console output that you're getting?

Comment: Im not getting issue while executing cURL. Eventhough <exec> task is failing im getting the below one as like it is success:    % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
100   381  100   381    0     0    381      0  0:00:01 --:--:--  0:00:01  6047

100 11816    0 11816    0     0  11816      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 11816
200

Comment: I'm still confused. I see no evidence of a failure. Is the problem that the contents of the downloaded config.xml aren't what you expect? (i e. curl writes to config.xml but it's just an authorization failure message inside?)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the erroproperty attribute, see [Ant manual exec task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html)

> errorproperty The name of a property in which the standard error of
>   the command should be stored. since Ant 1.6

Comment: It is not working by using the errorproperty. Can I get some other way ? How to get the error code of a curl command using groovy ?

Comment: Never had any problems with ant exec and getting exitcode, stdout, stderr.
cURL uses error output stream for progress output, see
https://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2008/12/using-groovy-to-invoke-curl-and-use.html

Comment: @Dinesh As cURL is using stderr for progress, use all attributes of the ecex task to catch all channels.